# Passar controle como parametro

Tags: vb.net

Olá, estou fazendo uma redução de algumas linhas de códigos em vb.net, um deles é uma função de pesquisa que cria um AutoComplete a partir de uma base de dados, o código que faz isso é o seguinte:

```
 Private Sub pesquisaNome(ByVal txtNome As TextBox)
    reconect()
    txtNome.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    txtNome.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

    strsql = "SELECT * FROM motorista WHERE motorista_nome LIKE '%" & txtNome.Text & "%'"
    Dim objCommand As New MySqlCommand(strsql, conn)
    dr_usuario = objCommand.ExecuteReader()

    While (dr_usuario.Read())
        txtNome.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(dr_usuario.Item("motorista_nome"))
    End While
End Sub
```

tenho tres campos de pesquisas diferente, um por Nome, outro por RG e outro por CPF, e cada um deles possui um codigo exatamente como esse, mudando apenas 3 argumentos, a cláusula do where (motorista_nome, motorista_rg etc...), o texto do controle TextBox (txtNome.text "nome do motorista", txtRG.text "numero do rg" etc. e o controle txtNome, txtRG etc..., resolvi criar uma função e passar por parâmetros esses valores:

```
Private Sub search(clausula As String, campo As String, controle As Object)
    strsql = "SELECT * FROM motorista WHERE" & clausula & " LIKE '%" & campo & "%'"
    Dim objCommand As New MySqlCommand(strsql, conn)
    dr_usuario = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While (dr_usuario.Read())
        controle.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(dr_usuario.Item(campo))
    End While
End Sub
```

e a passagem seria algo assim:

```
search("motorista_nome",txtnome,txtnome.text)
```

e minha duvida é justamente como passar o controle por parâmetro, ou se tem outra forma de juntar essas pesquisas em um código só??

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Por que `reconect()` está na primeira função e na segunda não?

Comment: Essa função é apenas pra renovar conexão, conn.close(), conn.open() sempre que alguma função vai interagir com a base de dados é necessario checar a conexão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta essa ai:

```
Private Sub search(clausula As String, campo As String, ByRef controle As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
   strsql = "SELECT * FROM motorista WHERE " & clausula & " LIKE '%" & campo & "%'"
   Dim objCommand As New MySqlCommand(strsql, conn)
   dr_usuario = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
   While (dr_usuario.Read())
      controle.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(dr_usuario.Item(clausula ))
   End While
End Sub
```

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO FERA! exatamente isso!! muito obrigado mesmo!